# random.choice from a constant lists without repeating?

Tags: python, list, random, constants

I am making a turtle street crossing game and I encountered an issue which I don't know how to solve. I've read several topics here about similar problems but they don't really help my particular case due to the fact that I am using constant lists, therefore the random.shuffle() option won't work for me.

Here's the class in question:

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

COLORS = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE = random.randint(3, 6)
MOVE_INCREMENT = 2
CAR_LANES_BOTTOM = [-220, -190, -160, -130, -100, -70, -40]
CAR_LANES_TOP = [40, 70, 100, 130, 160, 190, 220]


class CarManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bottom_cars = []
        self.top_cars = []

    def create_car_bottom(self):
        random_chance = random.randint(1, 20)
        if random_chance == 1:
            new_car = Turtle('square')
            new_car.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=2)
            new_car.penup()
            new_car.color(random.choice(COLORS))
            random_lane = random.choice(CAR_LANES_BOTTOM)
            new_car.goto(300, random_lane)
            self.bottom_cars.append(new_car)

    def create_car_top(self):
        random_chance = random.randint(1, 20)
        if random_chance == 1:
            new_car = Turtle('square')
            new_car.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=2)
            new_car.penup()
            new_car.color(random.choice(COLORS))
            random_lane = random.choice(CAR_LANES_TOP)
            new_car.goto(-300, random_lane)
            self.top_cars.append(new_car)

    def move_left(self):
        for car in self.bottom_cars:
            car.backward(random.randint(3, 6))

    def move_right(self):
        for car in self.top_cars:
            car.forward(random.randint(3, 6))
```

I am getting the cars generated in the same lane way too often and they're overlapping so I wanted to find a way to reduce the repetition somehow.

I have tried using time or increasing the random_chance range but it doesn't really affect the end result. After all the tests, I came to the conclusion that the only option would be to somehow ensure that this:

```
random_lane = random.choice(CAR_LANES_BOTTOM)
```

doesn't repeat lanes but I have no idea how to do that given the fact that the list is constant.
I will appreciate any ideas, suitable for a beginner like me.

Comment: What do you mean by "constant lists"? Can you expand on why `random.shuffle()` doesn't do what you want? Python doesn't have "constants".

Comment: What Q&As have you already read? I just checked a few and they gave more options than just `random.shuffle`, e.g. [Paul's answer on "How can I randomly select an item from a list?"](/a/30488952/4518341) or [clubby789's answer on "How to select random from list while excluding the previous random choice?"](/a/63926717/4518341)

Comment: Keep track of the items you have already chosen from the list, and if the random choice is one of those, choose again.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to choose values from your list of car lanes without having the lanes repeat.

There are a few different ways you could do this, and I will leave it to you to decide which is best.

### 1. Use [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) with a list copy

I know you started your question saying `random.shuffle()` doesn't work in your case, but I think there is a way to make it work.

You could make a copy of your list first, and then run `random.shuffle()` on it to make a list of lanes. Then each time `create_car_bottom()` is called it returns a value from that list.

Your code would look something like this:

```py
CAR_LANES_BOTTOM = [-220, -190, -160, -130, -100, -70, -40]

class CarManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bottom_cars = []
        ...
        self.bottom_cars_lane_order = []

    def create_car_bottom(self):
        if ...:
            if not self.bottom_cars_lane_order:
                # copy the list of car lanes
                self.bottom_cars_lane_order = list(CAR_LANES_BOTTOM)
                # shuffle it to have a random ordering
                random.shuffle(self.bottom_cars_lane_order)

            # Remove the last lane from lane order, and use it as the random lane
            random_lane = self.bottom_cars_lane_order.pop()
            ...
```

### 2. Make a custom function `random_unique()`

Another way to solve this problem is to make a custom function that will take your of car lanes, and your list of `bottom_cars`, and choose the next one.

Doing it this way avoids the need to maintain other list, but this is not as computationally efficient, as the `not_previously_selected` list needs to be recomputed every time.

```py
def random_unique(choices, previously_selected):
    """
    Choose a values from choices that has not previously_selected.
    """
    not_previously_selected = []
    for value in choices:
        if value not in previously_selected:
            not_previously_selected.append(value)

    return random.choice(not_previously_selected)
```

You could integrate this into your program as follows:

```py
CAR_LANES_BOTTOM = [-220, -190, -160, -130, -100, -70, -40]

class CarManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bottom_cars = []
        ...

    def create_car_bottom(self):
        if ...:
            random_lane = random_unique(CAR_LANES_BOTTOM, self.bottom_cars)
            ...
```

Comment: These look very neat but they gave me some errors so I went back to the original variant.

Comment: Sorry to hear you ran into an error with my answer. The double checked the code, and I don't see any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate with random elements using while loop. If you don't want to get same element from the list, you can create a 1 element list as used_coord and this element shouldn't be in CAR_LANES_BOTTOM.

After that, you can get your random value and check if the last element of used_coord matches with your random_coord, choose another coord till they do not match. It can help you to avoid getting the same coord in a row. You can adapt this code into your code. This code simply works as don't get elements from a list in a row. I hope it will be helpful to you.

Example Code:

```
used_coord = [1]
while(True):
        
    random_cord = random.choice(CAR_LANES_BOTTOM)
    
    
    try : #Check if your new random element match or not with last round.
        if used_coord[-1] != random_cord:
            used_coord.append(random_cord)
            break
        
    except :  
        print("Some Error")
```

If you want the last n elements to be different, you can use this code.

```
import random
CAR_LANES_BOTTOM = [-220, -190, -160, -130, -100, -70, -40]
used_coord = [1]*n
while(True):
        
    random_cord = random.choice(CAR_LANES_BOTTOM)

    try : 
        if random_cord not in used_coord[-n:]:
            used_coord.append(random_cord)
            break
        
    except : 
        print("Some Error")
```